# How to overlay one image over another image in iPhone

Tags: iphone, camera, uiimage, overlay

In my app i have one transparent image, now when user selects one image from photo library, that image have to be display over transparent image and make as an one uiiimage so that user can mail or share with it. I have used the following code, however image is not coming correct over transparent image

```
UIImage *backgroundImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"iPhoneOverLay.png"];

UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(backgroundImage.size);
[backgroundImage drawInRect:CGRectMake(0, 0, backgroundImage.size.width, backgroundImage.size.height)];
[testImage drawInRect:CGRectMake(backgroundImage.size.width - testImage.size.width, backgroundImage.size.height - testImage.size.height, testImage.size.width, testImage.size.height)];
UIImage *result = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
```

Here testImage is selected from Photo Library or taken from camera

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You draw the 2 images in the wrong order. Transparency is a property that makes things shine through that have been painted *previously*. Therefore you have to draw the (opaque) photo first and the (transparent) overlay second.